# Why do young witches & wizards know Voldemort's name?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

1. There is a taboo against speaking 'Voldemort' **at the beginning of Book One** (not **the Taboo** placed by the Ministry in Book Seven).
2. Every student Harry meets gasps at Harry's audacity in saying 'Voldemort' instead of You-know-who.
3. Point 2 means somebody told them the name, most likely their parents.
4. Point 3 means there is no taboo.

Is it because logic is a branch of mathematics, and maths and <del>JKR</del>magic don't mix well?

If wizarding parents were so afraid of Voldemort's memory to avoid mentioning him by name, why would they tell the name to their kids **and then** forbid them from using it? Makes as much sense as parents forcing children to learn the whole obscene vocabulary at the age of six, and then telling them not to use swearwords.

Comment: I assume it's much the same way that people learn other "unspeakable" words (swearwords and racial epithets) in common English. By hearing them said by those who don't care about the consequences, by reading them in books and literature aimed at adults and by hearing them spoken by adults when they don't think children are listening.

Comment: @Richard Except that unlike with swearwords and racial epithets, even adults fear to speak Voldemort's name, except a very few like Dumbledore.

Comment: @randal'thor  - Indeed, and when they speak it by accident, their children would learn that it's a **not nice word**

Comment: sex is handled very similar to a taboo and still usually when I were young most friends managed to figure out a mental image about it before the adults started to talk about it "officially". My point is when something is secret children usually have a much sharper eye than the adults who try to shadow their minds artificially.

Comment: @n611x007 - Comparing Voldemort and sex is ... interesting.

Comment: Your point 4 tells me you don't understand how actual societies treat taboo words.  Such words are never (properly) spoken *in public*.  However, indoctrination occurs *in private*.

Comment: @EricTowers - my experience is obviously different from yours.

Comment: You're doing that thing that people often do in sci-fi / fantasy arguments, where they assume that a general rule is a hard-set 100% accurate description.  We're talking about people.  Some of them are going to say Voldemort's name.

Comment: This question would be a much better one with some judicious editing to remove all the snark.

Comment: @Kyralessa - you can edit the Snark out of the question but you won't be able to hunt the Snark down. Yours truly, Charles Dodgson.

Comment: Math and Magic mixes well in some situations, but I suppose you are joking.

Comment: "Is it because logic is a branch of mathematics, and maths and JKRmagic don't mix well?" No, it's because you made a logical error in point 4; you assumed "taboo" means "no one can say it" when really it means "people don't say it in civilized/public fora". This is similar to the mistake that economists make when they expect people to act rationally with their dollars.

Comment: @TylerH To be fair, the error in #4 is actually not a *logical* error.  It's more of a lexical or sociological error.

Comment: @MishaRosnach True, I was just using the logic label that Deer Hunter was already using.

Comment: How did the Muggle Prime Minister learn the name? Fudge wrote it down for him, since he didn’t want to say it aloud. (Chapter _The other minister_ in HBP.)

Comment: Have *you* tried telling kids that there is a "thing (or person) that must not be named"?

Comment: @DeerHunter, it's different from words of sexual connotation or swear words. People aren't afraid of genitalia and sexual desires, they're ashamed.

Comment: Here is a better comparison: The Hitlergruß and Swastika in Germany. You absolutely don't do it in public, and yet at some point you learn about it. But possibly quite late. As a kid, I once built a Lego plane with a propeller in the shape of a swastika, not knowing the context and history. I was very confused how my parents were uneasy about it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### First, the Taboo (as opposed to *a* taboo) did not exist until Book 7

> “Sorry.” said Ron, wrenching Harry back out of the brambles, “but the
> name’s been jinxed. Harry, that’s how they track people! Using his
> name breaks protective enchantments, it causes some kind of magical
> disturbance—it’s how they found us in Tottenham Court Road!”

We see that the name *has been* jinxed; this is a new development. The opposite would not make any sense: why would the pre-Voldemort Ministry be interested in catching people who said Voldemort's name? Voldemort, on the other hand, knows that only those who stand up to him use his name as a matter of course:

> "You’ve got to give them credit, it makes sense. It was only people who
> were serious about standing up to him like Dumbledore, who ever dared
> use it. Now they’ve put a Taboo on it, anyone who says it is
> trackable—quick-and-easy way to find Order members!"

### **We also see that Hagrid is willing to say the name if necessary**

> He sat down, stared into the fire for a few seconds, and then said,
> "It begins, I suppose, with -- with a person called -- but it's
> incredible yeh don't know his name, everyone in our world knows --"
>
> "Who? "
>
> "Well -- I don' like sayin' the name if I can help it. No one does."
>
> "Why not?" "Gulpin' gargoyles, Harry, people are still scared. Blimey,
> this is difficult. See, there was this wizard who went... bad. As bad
> as you could go. Worse. Worse than worse. His name was..."
>
> Hagrid gulped, but no words came out.
>
> "Could you write it down?" Harry
> suggested.
>
> "Nah -can't spell it. All right -- Voldemort. " Hagrid
> shuddered. "Don' make me say it again. Anyway, this -- this wizard,
> about twenty years ago now, started lookin' fer followers. Got 'em,
> too -- some were afraid, some just wanted a bit o' his power, 'cause
> he was gettin' himself power, all right. Dark days, Harry. Didn't know
> who ter trust, didn't dare get friendly with strange wizards or
> witches... terrible things happened. He was takin' over. 'Course, some
> stood up to him -- an' he killed 'em. Horribly. One o' the only safe
> places left was Hogwarts. Reckon Dumbledore's the only one
> You-Know-Who was afraid of. Didn't dare try takin' the school, not
> jus' then, anyway."

I'm sure there were many other wizards, particularly when people still though Voldemort was gone, who were willing to say Voldemort's name, but simply very reluctant to do so. The setup would be very similar. Young children would wonder why, for example, their relatives were dead. (Remember that many wizarding families lost relatives in the first war in Britain). Then their parents would have to tell them, and would reluctantly hand over Voldemort's name.

**Don't forget: Voldemort is a constant topic of conversation.**

When a massive war happened barely a decade before, the phrase "You-Know-Who" will be on everyone's lips. Once a child has picked up a modicum of language, it would only be natural to say, "No, I don't know who." And then their parents have to explain to them in hushed voices who they are actually talking about, and not to say his name. Most people, I imagine, were not *so* devoted to not saying Voldemort's name that they would refuse even to whisper it to their children. I suspect that most people could write it down, to start with.

And that's really the answer: **Voldemort is someone that you *need* to know about.** People may use euphemisms, but they know his real name. It's a bit like how people often used to say "passed away" instead of died, almost uniformly, for the sake of politeness, but everyone still knew the name of death.

Comment: There goes me spending time to update my answer. I guess I'll just +1 and move along.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85853 . Your answer makes sense.

Comment: And of course, for the kids whose parents won't say Voldemort's name, the kids in their age group will be more than happy to, either not understanding the taboo or wanting to sound tough.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to call him, say, Henry instead. Just tell the kids his name is Henry, and then you don't need to deal with the "He who must not be named" business.

Comment: @PyRulez or maybe something like Tom or Marvolo or Riddle?

Answer (score 5):

The Taboo was placed after the ministry fell in book seven. Before that there was nothing preventing people from saying the name, save general superstition.

> Now they’ve put a Taboo on it, anyone who says it is  trackable  —  quick-and-easy way  to find Order members!  They nearly  got Kingsley —”
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Chapter 20*)</sub>

To quote [Richard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123228/why-do-young-witches-wizards-know-voldemorts-name#comment305263_123228), We can assume that children would learn about "Voldemort" the same way they learn other "unspeakable words" such as swearwords and racial epithets.

> By hearing them said by those who don't care about the consequences, by reading them in books and literature aimed at adults and by hearing them spoken by adults when they don't think children are listening.

Comment: You are mistaking the Trace and the taboo which was widespread at the beginning of book 1. Swear words don't carry the same charge in the wizarding world as Voldemort's name.

Comment: @DeerHunter - The Trace was widespread since before book one. The Taboo started partway through book seven. It seems that the primary reason Voldemort's name was avoided before that was due to superstition and fear. (Similar to how people in LotR refuse to say "Sauron" and "Mordor").

Comment: Hardly any adult wizard will pronounce 'Voldemort'. Nowhere to learn from, I'm afraid.

Comment: ibid, thank you for the clarification. That's one thing I need to fix in the question.

Comment: @DeerHunter - When pressured, even Hagrid says it. I'd assume that other adult wizards will also.